# Boundness of the operator when Hamel basis vectors are eigenvectors

Tags: functional-analysis, hamel-basis

Let $X$ be infinite-dimensional Banach space, $\{e_j\}_{j\in J}$ be normalized Hamel basis for it.

Suppose for each $j\in J$ we choose a number $\lambda_j\in\mathbb{R}$. Then we define a linear map
$$A:X\to X$$
$$Ae_j = \lambda_je_j$$
and extend by linearity.

Is it possible to say something about boundness of $A$ knowing the set $\Lambda = \{\lambda_j\: |\: j\in J\}$? Suppose $0\not\in\Lambda$ so $A$ is a bijection.

Trivially if $\Lambda$ is unbounded then $A$ is unbounded too. If $0$ is a limit point of $\Lambda$ then $A$ is a bijection with unbounded inverse, so it also must be unbounded.

What if $\Lambda$ is bounded and is away from zero?

Can anything be done in a general case? Any necessary/sufficient conditions?

Comment: Select a Banach basis $(e_{j_k})$ from $(e_j)$. The given $\lambda_{j_k}$ values must determine by means of limits all the other $\lambda_j$ if $A$ is bounded.

Comment: @Berci, what is Banach basis? If you refer to Shauder basis for $X$, it may not exist. If it exists it is not clear to me why it is possible to choose it from given Hmel basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Say $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and $Y$ is not closed. Say $B_1$ is a Hamel basis for $Y$ and let $B$ be a Hamel basis for $X$ with $B_1\subset B$.

Let $$\lambda_j=\begin{cases}1,&(e_j\in B_1),
\\2,&(e_j\notin B_1).\end{cases}$$

Now if $A$ were continuous then $Y=\{x: Ax=x\}$ would be closed.

Comment: So if think about $\Lambda$ as a function (not mere set): $J\to\mathbb{R}$, $j\mapsto\lambda_j$,  $\Lambda$ should not attain two values infinitely many times. I mean for $A$ to be bounded.

Comment: @sas It would be better if you decided what the question was before asking it..

Comment: It's a natural thing to think deeper about a problem after getting a solution for simple version, no? Nevermind, thank you